# Prevent floats on a single page OR change page margins for a single page

Tags: floats, margins, geometry

I've got a particular problem with a custom chapter style. Essentially my chapter title is on the *left* page, then there is a picture on top of the right page (waves, see below) and below the picture, the chapter content (bla ble bli blo) starts.

```
+--------+--------+
|        |~~~~~~~~|
| Ch. 6  |~~~~~~~~|
|        |        |
|        |bla ble |
|        |bli blo |
+--------+--------+
```

I've got it working using a modification of `\chapter{}` for the left page, then

```
\newpage
\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1.0}{waves}
\phantom{placeholder}
\vspace{200pt}
```

and then the chapter content starts.

The problem is that floats don't know the top right area is taboo for them, so I might get:

```
+--------+--------+
|        |~[    ]~|
| Ch. 6  |~[Fig1]~|
|        |        |
|        |        |
|        |bla ble |
+--------+--------+
```

So `{figure}` first, then placeholder and `\vspace`, then content.

I've been looking into two solutions without success:

A) Preventing floats on this first page. I don't know how to do this without affecting all of the document (i.e. flafter) or setting the very first float manually to `[b]`. I haven't found a way to tell floats to just avoid a certain page or a certain area.

B) Setting the top margin for this page only. I've looked into `geometry` package, namely

```
\newgeometry{top=300pt}
\restoregeometry
```

But this doesn't work. First of all, `\newgeometry` uses `\clearpage`, but I don't want clearpages, I just want to change one page margin. I've deleted the clearpages and made my own `\newcommands`, but...

```
\newsamepagegeometry{top=300pt}
\restoresamepagegeometry
```

...doesn't work because it both sets *and* unsets the margins for the current page, instead of setting them for the current page and unsetting them for the next.

So I tried `\afterpage{...}` but there seems to be a known (or at least observed) issue that prevents

```
\newsamepagegeometry{top=300pt}
\afterpage{\restoresamepagegeometry}
```

from working, while manual placement of `\restoresamepagegeometry` among the next page text works fine. The above code apparently does not execute `\restoresamepagegeometry` at all, so the geometry remains at `top=300pt` for the rest of the document.

Any solution or an idea where to look would be most appreciated.

Comment: Hi! First, I'd like to say that this is an extra-ordinary first question, if only every question on the site showed such a quality! Second, notice that you can use backticks `\`...\`` to format the inline code pieces, as I did in my edit. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 3):

Your chapter heading can do the same as article.cls `\maketitle` which is

```
\global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
```

the setting is global but only affects the current page. Depending on the context, you might need to [use `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do).